# Class & Properties - Java

Tags: java, string, class, printing, properties

I am new to java and have been set a task to create a class called Manual along with some properties shown in the question below:

> "1. Design a class Manual with the following properties:
>
> serial number - string, - default:??????
>
> title - string, - default: Untitled
>
> author - string, - default: Unknown
>
> Write a constructor and a method to print details of a Manual on the console.
>   "

I have been working on this task and so far I have this:

```
public class Manual {

    String serialNumber, title, author;

    public Manual(){
        serialNumber = "??????";
        title = "Untitled";
        author = "Unknown";
    }

}
```

Would anyone be able to let me know if my working so far is correct and also how I might be able to complete the last line referring to a constructor / print method.

Thank you

Comment: Seems right ;) for the last task take a look at java System.out.print()

Comment: You already write a constructor. Just write a method to print : `public void printDetails(){System.out.println("S.no= " +serialNumber+" Title= "+ title+"author= "+author)}`

Comment: This [seems familiar...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507842/class-creation-properties-java)

Comment: @JonK There is a difference. OP tried to max and asking for help. That's ok.

Comment: Default values may be defined at variable creation.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Thanks for your helpful reply, I tried adding the line of code you sent me but when I click run eclipse states the section cannot be run, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @05K3 You need a main method to run any Java programm. Research that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than that print, you need to have a main method to run.

```
public class Manual {

    String serialNumber, title, author;

    public Manual(){
        serialNumber = "??????";
        title = "Untitled";
        author = "Unknown";
    }

public void printDetails(){
   System.out.println("S.no= " +serialNumber+" Title= "+ title+"author= "+author)

}

public static void main(String [] args){
        Manual man= new Manual();
        man.printDetails();
    }

}
```

Edit after comment:

I just tried to give a mock code and , you must aware of the access modifiers to your members in the class. This is what your actual task. Learn them and experiment with them.

I wrote a small tutorial on the same, try to read and understand.
[Default access modifier in Java (or) No access modifier in Java](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/09/default-access-modifier-in-java-or-no.html)

Good luck.

Comment: And how would he/she construct a `Manual` object with non default values? And how would one access the properties of a `Manual`? I guess this is what the instructor wants to see as solution...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct so far. For the printing you should use

```
System.out.println("Manual details : ");
System.out.println("Serial Number : "+serialNumber);
System.out.println("Author : "+author);
System.out.println("Title : "+title);
```